# How to compute $\prod_{n=2}^{\infty} \left(1-\frac{1}{n^n}\right)$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, infinite-product

Does
       $$\prod_{n=2}^{\infty} \left(1-\frac{1}{n^n}\right)$$
have any closed form in terms of known mathematical constants?

Comment: Since the corresponding logsum is closely related to sophomore's dream, i doubt a closed form

Comment: I just checked Wolfram-Mathworld: [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cprod_%7Bn%3D2%7D%5E%7B%5Cinfty%7D+%5Cleft(1-%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Bn%5En%7D%5Cright)) it seems $\prod_{n=2}^{\infty} \left(1-\frac{1}{n^n}\right)$  has a closed form I think the "product to sum" appoarch would work here